# Tick interval on highcharts plot is integer

Tags: highcharts

For some reason tick interval on every chart is an interger value. There are no **thickInterval** settings, though.

When the data values are small like:

```
[["1", 0], ["2", 0.01], ["3", 0.01], ["Average", 0.01]]
```

then thick interval is set to **0**.

Accordingly column chart looks like this:
[image]

How may I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

1) check that `allowDecimals` is not set to false

2) check that the axis label formatter is not set in a way that would exclude decimals

3) set the tickInterval explicitly

For better info, provide a fiddle example of your chart demonstrating the problem.

Reference:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.allowDecimals